# Doctrine bulk insert - How to fix "Out of memory" with bulk insert using Doctrine / Symfony 4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4, bulkinsert

When I am trying to get metadata from a supplier I am converting the data to our own metadata format. But because of the sheer size of the imported data the application gets a OutOfMemoryException.

I tried several things. Like pumping up the memory that may be used and also I tried using [Doctrine Batch Processing](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html) but there is a small problem with this approach. Doctrine data processing is based on a 'for' loop with indexation.

```php
$batchSize = 20;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
    $user = new CmsUser;
    $user->setStatus('user');
    $user->setUsername('user' . $i);
    $user->setName('Mr.Smith-' . $i);
    $em->persist($user);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
}
$em->flush(); //Persist objects that did not make up an entire batch
$em->clear();
```

But the data I import is a multi-layered array which I created in a threedimensional 'foreach' loop:

```php
$this->index = 0;
$batchSize = 100;
foreach ($response as $item) {
    $item = new Item;
    $item->setName($item->name);
    $item->setStatus($item->status);
    $em->persist($item);
    if (($this->index % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush();
        $em->clear();
    }
    foreach ($item->category as $category) {
        $category = new Category;
        $category->setName($category->name);
        $category->setStatus($category->status);
        $em->persist($item);
        if (($this->index % $batchSize) === 0) {
            $em->flush();
            $em->clear();
        }
        foreach ($category->suppliers as $supplier) {
            $supplier = new Supplier;
            $supplier->setName($supplier->name);
            $supplier->setStatus($supplier->status);
            $em->persist($item);
            if (($this->index % $batchSize) === 0) {
                $em->flush();
                $em->clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
$this->em->flush();
```

This is fictional code to illustrate my problem. With this the application still gets OutOfMemoryException and I do have the feeling that the batching methode isn't working properly.

I would like to get the memory usage down so the application works properly or would like some advice to try and find a other approach to this problem. Like making a background process that just takes care of the import on the background.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your nested `foreach` loops you will obviously consume resources exponentially. I also suspect it's not going to achieve what you really want since you will have a LOT of duplicate `Supplier`s and `Category`s.

Working with full entities in doctrine also carries a tremendous amount of overhead, but it does have some advantages so I'll assume that you are wanting to do so.

My approach to bulk imports like this has been to work from the bottom up. In your case it might be a variant of what I have below. The assumption is that you have data in an existing database, and each existing "entity" in the old database will have its own unique `id`.

1- Import all suppliers from old db to new db; in the new db have a column named `oldId` that references the unique `id` from the old db. Stop to clear cache/memory.

2- Pull all suppliers from the new database into an array indexed by their `oldId`. I use code like so:

```
$suppliers = [];
$_suppliers = $this->em->getRepository(Supplier:class)->findAll();
foreach ($_suppliers as $supplier) {
    $suppliers[$supplier->getOldId()] = $supplier;
}
```

3- Repeat step 1 for categories. During the import your old db will have a reference to the `oldId` of linked suppliers. Although your code does not do this, I assume you want to maintain the link between supplier and category, so you can now reference the supplier by its `oldId` within a loop over the linked "old" suppliers:

```
$category->addSupplier($suppliers[ <<oldSupplier Id>> ]);
```

4- Repeat above for individual items, only this time saving the linked categories.

Obviously there are a lot of tweaks that can improve on this. The main point is that touching each supplier once, then touching each category once, and then touching each item once when done sequentially will be orders of magnitude faster and less resource intensive than trying to tackle in a deeply nested loop.